# Error while running the SQL to fetch data from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to find what is wrong with the code below as I keep seeing the error saying `mysql_fetch_array()` expects parameter 1 to be mysql. I know that the issue is with the SQL statement itself. The first SQL statement is successfully executed, populating the DB with the inserted data. Please have a look to see what could have gone wrong with the SQL statement. Thanks a lot.

```
$address      = addslashes($_POST['address']);
$query        = mysql_query("insert into crd_article_desc(article_desc,article_title,article_category) values ('$address','$_POST[title]','$_POST[category]')");
$query        = mysql_query("SELECT article_desc from crd_article_desc where article_title=$_POST[title]");
$article_desc = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

Using mysql, not mysqli.

Comment: sql injection alert. Also you might want to change the variable names. You have $query twice.

Comment: error showing `mysqli` but your code is `mysql`

Comment: @Gaurav. It is mysql not mysqli. I am sorry for the typos.

Comment: Please use either mysqli or pdo. mysql functions are no longer supported.

Comment: @phpdev. Yes. I am using mysqli on all current projects. The example I had issue with is from an old script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use single quotes for string like this:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query(
        "SELECT 
            article_desc 
        FROM 
            crd_article_desc 
        WHERE 
            article_title='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']) . "'"
);
```

Comment: @Pramod, please accept my answer if it really helped you :)

Comment: Yes! Most definitely in a few mins as it won't allow to accept answers within a few minutes of posting the answer.

Comment: @Pramod Thanks bro :)